Is it possible to display bars instead of an area in DataZoom with Apache ECharts?
I am working on a bar chart using Apache ECharts, and I want to customize the dataZoom component. By default, the dataZoom slider typically displays as an area chart representation. However, I would like the dataZoom to display bars instead, mimicking the main chart.
Is it possible to configure the dataZoom component in Apache ECharts to render as bars rather than an area? If so, how can I achieve this?
Here’s a simplified version of my chart configuration:
option = {
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
    },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'value'
    },
    series: [
        {
            data: [10, 52, 200, 334, 390, 330, 220],
            type: 'bar'
        }
    ],
    dataZoom: [
        {
            type: 'slider',
            start: 0,
            end: 100
        }
    ]
};

If this functionality isn't natively supported, are there any workarounds or alternative approaches that I could consider?
Thanks in advance for your help!

You can at least disable it with showDataShadow. I think you would need to alter the source code to achieve what you are looking for.
